# Oracle DB:How we can write Query for insert record in the table if records already exist then record is not inserted otherwise record inserted

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

How we can write Query for insert record in the table if records already exist then record is not inserted otherwise record inserted.

**How we can convert it into SQL Query. select the same table and insert the same table if the record does not exist.**

```
//SQL Sudo Code Like This:
IF ("select count(*) from table_name where name = ? and status = ? and salary = ?"==0):
       // if this is true then we use insert statement.
       INSERT INTO table_name(col1,col2,col3,col4) values(?,?,?,?);
```

Comment: Your pseudo code actually implies that you want to insert the new record if the data _does_ already exist.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: if a record already exists we do not perform insert operation otherwise we do insert operations. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4)
    SELECT ?,
           ?,
           ?,
           ?
      FROM DUAL
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
          FROM TABLE_NAME
         WHERE NAME = ?
           AND STATUS = ?
           AND SALARY = ?
    )
```

Comment: great solution. but I'll suggest instead of doing this OP should know what this table purpose is and just simply have a PK that block the unwanted duplicate.

Comment: @T.Peter we will do using PK but in my case, all these columns are not PK.

Comment: @Tejash  it works,thanks

Comment: @RaviRanjan You should accept the answer if it resolved your issue so that this question is marked as resolved.